# Integration by parts: Hydrostatic pressure

Tags: calculus, integration

The question itself is:

A diving pool that is 4 meters deep, and full of water, has on one of its walls a circular viewing window, tangent to the bottom of the pool, with a radius of .5 meters. Find the force on this window.

I have the integral $\int_0^1 1000\cdot9.8\cdot(4-y)\sqrt{0.25-y^2}\,\mathrm dx$, and I have absolutely no idea how to work with it. I've tried multiple different approaches and every time I simply cannot do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that for $y>1/2$, $0.25-y^2<0$. Maybe the upper bound of the integral is not $1$?

Comment: Which approaches have you tried?  Can you find $\int 4 \sqrt{0.25 - y^2}\,dy$ and $\int y \sqrt{0.25 - y^2}\,dy$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I have tried this, but get stuck there as well. I'm severely struggling with this problem on all fronts.

Comment: “If you can't solve a problem, then there is an easier problem you also can't solve: find it” (Polyà).  It sounds like you want to try to find those two antiderivatives.  The second is easier than the first.

Comment: Am I missing something? Does the added question have to do with the problem?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang The quote is *"If you can't solve a problem, then there is an easier problem you **can** solve: find it."*, but somehow I prefer your version.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: My certainly led me to reread all of *How to Solve It* twice and I couldn't find it either way.  Then I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086285).  Apparently Conway attributed it to Polyà with *can't*.  The way I always thought about it, the idea is simplify the problem as much as you can, without removing the part that makes it difficult.  So you can't find $\int\sqrt{0.25-y^2}\,dy$?  What about $\int\sqrt{1-y^2}\,dy$ isntead?  That's easier, but maintains the essential hardness of the first.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Write it as

$(1000•9.8•4)-(1000•9.8•y )(0.25-y^2)^{0.5}$

then use the substitution $0.25-y^2=y$ for the second part and integrate the first part manually.

Comment: How did you separate the integral into those two parts? the y is being subtracted from 4, and there it looks like you completely took it apart.

Comment: I multiplied the constants together and then multiplied them by $y$.  If you have $a(b-c)$ you can write it as $ab-ac$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Split the integrand into two parts: the first a constant multiple of $\sqrt{0.25-y^2},$ and the second a constant multiple of $-y\sqrt{0.25-y^2}.$ You may do the first by using the substitution $$y=\frac12\sin\phi.$$ To do the second, use the substitution $u=0.25-y^2.$